# Casting a Firebase timestamp to a Date/Time in BigQuery - referencing a computed field again in the same query?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, firebase-extensions

I am not a coder, and very much flying blind, so please excuse the simplicity of this query.

I am streaming Firebase Firestore updates to a BigQuery table using the Firebase extension "Stream collection to BigQuery" which I am then linking as a DataSource in Google Data Studio. This is currently working as intended.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a more efficient way to convert a Firebase timestamp into a BigQuery Date/Time value? The Firebase Timestamp shows in JSON format in the BigQuery table as follows:

   `{"created_time":{"_seconds":1647554254,"_nanoseconds":234000000}}`

   My BigQuery SQL code to convert it (which works) is:

   `DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(JSON_VALUE(DATA,'$.created_time._seconds') AS int64)),"Africa/Johannesburg") AS createDate`

   Is there a more efficient way to do this, or is this reasonable?
2. How do I reference the `createDate` computed field (above) in another computed field `ageDays` within this same query? I haven't found it in Google or StackOverflow, either because of poor phrasing or its just too basic a query. I tried using a table alias referencing the `createDate` computed field (e.g. `T.createDate`) but no dice. My very ugly workaround was therefore just to reperform the `createDate` calculation in it's entirety (which feels wrong) in my new computed column `ageDays` as follows:

   `DATE_DIFF(current_date("Africa/Johannesburg"),DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(JSON_VALUE(DATA,'$.created_time._seconds') AS int64)),"Africa/Johannesburg"), DAY) AS ageDays`

[image: Screenshot in situ]

Would be sincerely grateful for any insights - many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your requirement, [JSON_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract) can also be used instead of JSON_VALUE. You can use below query to get the expected output.

```
select
 date(timestamp_seconds(cast(json_extract( data , '$.created_time._seconds') as int64))) AS Date_Created
from `project.dataset.timetable`
```

**Output**

[image]

Table [alias](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#using_aliases) cannot be used to reference a field in another column with a [SELECT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select-list_aliases) statement as it has limited visibility. Alias can be used with Order By, Group By or Having clauses in a SELECT statement. The best way to get the `ageDays` is by again computing the whole `createDate` field.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my questions - greatly appreciated 